# Check if prev id in a loop is not same as current

Tags: javascript

Lets say there is an array of objects

```js
array = [
  { id : 1, name: 'aaa' },
  { id : 1, name: 'asd' },
  { id : 2, name: 'asd' }
]
```

in a loop eg

```js
array.forEach(a => {
  currentId = a.id 
});
```

how to check if current id is same or not as prev id ?

Comment: u can access index `array.forEach((a,idx) ` then idx-1 can used to get prev element. make sure u handle case when index = 0

Comment: When you say "previous ID", do you mean all the IDs you've encountered before, or just the ID in the entry immediately before the current one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the index to get the previous entry:

```js
array = [{ id : 1, name : 'aaa' }, { id : 1, name: 'asd' }, {id : 2, name : 'asd'} ]

array.forEach((a, index) =>{
  let currentId = a.id

  // Check if previous exists (Index will be 0 on first run)
  if (index) {
    let previousId = array[index - 1].id
    // If exists we can check it
    console.log(currentId === previousId)
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) like:

```js
const array = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'aaa'
}, {
  id: 1,
  name: 'bbb'
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'cccc'
},
{
  id:2,
  name:'ddd'
}];

array.reduce((prev, next) => {
    if (prev.id === next.id) {
      console.log(`${prev.name} has same id of ${next.name}`);
    }
    return next;
});
```

Comment: Yes that i know but i need to use foreach. thanks though. its more like its a list of downloading files in a zip and if the id is same it should add in the same folder. the bottom answer did it for me.

Comment: You can do the same here but ok :D